# Deploying a privileged test app on FirefoxOS device

Tags: firefox-os

Is there any way I can distribute a "privileged" app prior to marketplace approval?

It's kinda hassle for me to "push" app to the device using Firefox OS Simulator every time I need to test it. Would it be great if I can just point my browser to app's html file and then it will automatically re-install the app? Just like what android *.apk does.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install a privileged app on a real device without the simulator dashboard (or app manager) if you didn't submit it to the marketplace first (and was approved). For security reasons, the application needs to be signed, so it's why you need to publish it to the marketplace.